# Change color of dropdown background color

Tags: jquery, forms, css

The background color for my property address picker dropdown is currently transparent and I'd like to make it white, can't seem to figure it out no matter how much I mess with it:

http://realendeavors.com/dmv-form/thank-you2.htm

Also would like to make the cursor a pointer when the user hovers over suggested property addresses. I've tried adding "cursor:pointer" into jquery.timepicker.min.css but can't get that to work either. Any ideas?

I believe the code affecting the dropdown would be in here:

```
    .ui-timepicker-container{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;box-sizing:border-box}.ui-timepicker{box-sizing:content-box;display:block;height:205px;list-style:none outside none;margin:0;padding:0 1px;text-align:center;}.ui-timepicker-viewport{box-sizing:content-box;display:block;height:205px;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden}.ui-timepicker-standard{font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid #AAA;color:#222;margin:0;padding:2px}.ui-timepicker-standard a{border:1px solid;color:#222;display:block;padding:.2em .4em;text-decoration:none}.ui-timepicker-standard .ui-state-hover{background-color:#DADADA;border:1px solid #999;font-weight:400;color:#212121}.ui-timepicker-standard .ui-menu-item{margin:0;padding:0}.ui-timepicker-corners,.ui-timepicker-corners .ui-corner-all{-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}.ui-timepicker-hidden{display:none}.ui-timepicker-no-scrollbar .ui-timepicker{border:0}
```

Comment: Please share your code...so people can help you.

Comment: Everyone of the questions you've posted is vague and contains the same link. Even after people have commented, guiding you on how to ask a well structured question. This seems more like advertising spam than a genuine question

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what code is affecting it, as I'm just editing a template. I believe it's in http://realendeavors.com/dmv-form/jquery.timepicker.min.css but I'm not sure...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, what pray tell would I be advertising with a thank you page that says nothing of a product/service? I'm just new to all this and trying to learn as I go.

Comment: Your domain is a real-estate service. SO is a well known target for SEO link builders.

Comment: Yes and links posted here are no-follow, and I wouldn't promote a thank you page if I was looking to rank. I could care less about SEO, I plan to run Facebook ads to generate leads.

Comment: In which case please listen to people when they ask you to improve your questions to make them clearer; ie. include the relevant code in the question. If you're still unsure of how to do this, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guides. Thanks

Comment: Will do, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your custom CSS file

```
span.tt-dropdown-menu {
   background-color: #fff;
}

span.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestions .tt-suggestion {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Any idea how I could also add a border between the dropdown items? I tried:

   select.tt-dropdown-menu {
   border:solid;
   border-color:#000;
}

Didn't work...

Comment: Try select.tt-dropdown-menu { border: 1px solid #000; }

Comment: Updated the answer to include border for each suggestions

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you again!!